# How to change the background color of button on Click Event in Universal Windows Platform Apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm working on a UWP app in windows 10 and I am trying to change the background color of a button in a click event. This is my code:

```
private void button1_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_Sign)
    {
        button_1_1.Content = "Cross";
        _Sign = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // button_1_1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Windows.UI.Color )    

        // indows.UI.Colors clr = new Windows.UI.Colors(new SolidColorBrush red);

        // SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush();
        // color = new SolidColorBrush.
        // button_1_1.Background = clr;

        button_1_1.Content = "Tick";
        _Sign = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have better luck doing it in XAML rather than code behind. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414686/wpf-changing-button-background-on-click) might help.

Comment: yes it's good but I need to change the color from C# code as I'm working on different scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the predefined color objects from the [Colors properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.colors):

```
button_1_1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
```

Comment: Seems like SolidColorBrush no longer exists in UWP now?

Answer (score 1):

You can do just that

```
button1.SetValue(BackgroundProperty,new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black));
```

You can play with that! I am not on my pc now to check it but something like that works.

or you can try

```
button1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.Ui.Colors.Black);
```

Comment: "BackgroundPropert***y***" and "U***I***". Just mentioning so people can copy / paste without errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide different color

```
 SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
   mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 244, 244);
 button1.Background = mySolidColorBrush;
```

U have to just convert a color code to Argb like this

```
return new SolidColorBrush(
                Color.FromArgb(
                    255,
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16)
                )
            );
```

its very easy and proper because you can give any color not a default color like black ,orange etc.