# How to change the backcolor of a Button in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, background-color

There are a few identical questions in SO asking about changing the background color of a button in UWP (Universal Windows Platform):

[How to change the background color of button in Universal Windows Platform Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463749/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-button-in-universal-windows-platform-apps)

[how to change background color of button in UWP Apps in c# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077231/how-to-change-background-color-of-button-in-uwp-apps-in-c-sharp)

However, it seems that Microsoft has been changing things. `SolidColorBrush` can no longer be found. I have tried using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush` and `Windows.UI.Colors`. None of those work.

Mouse hovering over button.background, the hint shows that background is expecting type: `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush`.

[image]

**My Question**: How do I change the background color of a button using c# codes? If I use the suggested solutions  in other identical posts, namespace `SolidColorBrush` will not be found.

Comment: What error does it give when you do `btnStart.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported the following namespace?

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Media
```

Because if have not, you won't be access the SolidColorBrush Class directly, 
and will have to do so by:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush mycolor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
```

In this example, I have created a SolidColorBrush with the Color of Blue, and I have setit directly, without any kind of conversion, like this:

```
myButton.Background = mycolor;
```

In case you want to create your own color, you can utilize the `Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb` method, where you can even specify the alpha of your Color.

### Edit:

Looking back on your answer, I have realized that you were trying to create your `Brush`, which would set the `Background` of a button control, with the `Brush` class. The Brush class is the parent for several derived brushes classes, all with different purposes. One of them is the `SolidColorBrush` class.