# Listview fore color will be unchanged in selection mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, textblock

I have the below XAML

however I want when the user box clicked on any of the textblock in he list view I want the forecolor of the text to be unchanged (currently changed to white)
instead I want the border color to be changed
how can I do that?

```
ListView x:Name="LV" ItemsSource= "{Binding  Lggv}"     SelectionChanged="dataGridData_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel >
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info }" AllowDrop="True"  >
                                    <TextBlock.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">                                              
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFCEE6C6" Offset="0.008"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF9ECF8C" Offset="0.987"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </TextBlock.Background>



                                </TextBlock>


                            </Border>
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC5DDFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA8C8F7" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}" ></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ComPort}"></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" ></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>    


                </ListView.ItemTemplate>


            </ListView>
```

Comment: Well the easiest way is to change the visual  state in xaml.cs  - just add handler to StackPanel on MouseClick and name all the necessary elements. Than in handler find those elements using VisualTree and change the parameters you want.

Comment: I don't really think that's how it's done in WPF, yours is rather a WinForm way (IMO). A cleaner solution would be using `Triggers` and `Styles`. Here's a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388429/how-to-set-mouseover-event-trigger-for-border-in-xaml or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414686/wpf-changing-button-background-on-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should distinguish between the item content and the item container. Handling item selection style should be the responsibility of the container. The following style defines a replacement for the visual representation of a `ListViewItem` with some basic properties. Depending on your desired visual, you may want to define a different style.

Define the style as resource:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The item will be displayed differently when the mouse is over (background color) and when the item is selected (red border). The foreground should stay untouched with this.

Usage:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    <!-- your other code -->
</ListView>
```