# Multiple styles and content on one button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `HomePage` with a number of buttons on that I am trying to get to do a couple of things. Firstly, I have a `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary` that dictates the overall 'look and feel' of the buttons. It looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="HomeButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#06658D"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#06658D"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Nothing too complicated, however I want the MouseOver effect to persist after being clicked. So now I am looking at doing something like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HomeButton}" Content="Contacts">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContactsClicked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#06658D"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button>
```

I'll bind the command element of the Button to set `ContactsClicked = true` and reset this when another button is pressed. However, I get the error saying that Content is set multiple times.

Is it possible to have an overall `Style` of the `Button` set, as well as a 'Clicked`style and to have a`TextBlock`displaying text on the button all at once or am I approaching this wrong? I am trying to not have an individual overall style for every single`Button`as that's a lot of repeated code.

For clarity this is what I am aiming for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution myself, instead of using a `Button` us a `ToggleButton` instead:

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="HomeButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#06658D"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#06658D"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#06658D"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Shame, it was definitely possible using a button. I was about to suggest something from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25414917/6741868). Anyways, glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score -1):

I would add this as a comment but im not allowed.

If your goal is that the button will stay selected after it is clicked, why not use a `RadioButton`? A `RadioButton` has a built-in property called `IsChecked` but will also remain "Checked" or "Selected" even after multiple clicks.

Of course you can define the behavior and the styles in a similar manner, create a simple `Trigger` on the property `IsChecked`.

If more explanation is needed, just say so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I haven't though of using a `RadioButton` actually, is it possible to Style it in the way of a normal button? For example could I remove the usual circle that says whether it is selected or not? I would struggle to see how I could style it to look like the above.

Comment: Of course! You could style anything to look like anything, buttons are the most simple actually.  Here is the control template:[Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms751600(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Carefully remove what you don't need. I can give you a complete example if needed

Comment: Wow that seems like a crazy amount of code just for me to change the background of a Button to white when it is clicked! There must be a simpler way...

Comment: Actually, there isn't. And believe me, I know what i'm talking about. Keeping that in mind, you should delete most of that code as I mentioned. Everything related to the VisualStatesManager as well

Comment: So basically, all of the bottom code snippets are brushes that are unrelevant to you. You only need the top code snippet. There, you only have the basic visual structure of the control and the Triggers that control the behavior. Not so much code in my opinion.